# How to create a session for Azure IotHub with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

In the past I used [IoTHub Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer/) for logging in and creating a session to then do further operations (like calling device methods). IoTHub Explorer has been deprecated by Microsoft. (I'm doing some application-level test automation)

How can I create sessions as I did with the explorer using the azure CLI `az`?

Here is what I did in the past:

```
iothub-explorer login "HostName=..."
iothub-explorer device-method <device> "<method>" ...
```

Here is what I do now:

```
az iot hub invoke-device-method -l "HostName=..." -n <hub-name> -d <device -method-name <method>
```

As can be seen, I have to provide the `-l`-option to every call to `az iot`. Ideally I can avoid this by creating a session.

I tried to use `az login` which opens a website, not ideal for test-automation. And even after then, calling `az iot hub invoke-device-method` without `-l` leads to an exception: `AttributeError: 'IotHubResourceOperations' object has no attribute 'config'`

I tried to generate a `sas-token` but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my azure-cli environment was not properly set up: refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15461. Do not mix up Debian/system packages of azure-cli (do not use actually) and pip installed ones. Do everything with pip, *either* as a user *or* as root.

I created a new virtualenv to clean it:

```
$ virtualenv ~/python-venv/azure-venv
$ . ~/python-venv/azure-cli/bin/activate
(azure-venv) $ pip install azure-cli
(azure-venv) $ az login
(azure-venv) $ az iot hub generate-sas-token --duration 3600 -n <hubname> -l <login-string>
(azure-venv) $ az iot hub invoke-device-method -n <hub-name> -d <device --method-name <method>
```

And it works.